# C++ Vector Matrix Seg faults :(

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
#include<unistd.h> 

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> >matrix1c;
vector<vector<int> >matrix2c;
vector<vector<int> >matrix3c;

int maxelement;
int totalelement;
int step_i = 0;
int r1c;
int c1c;
int r2c;
int c2c;

void* multi(void* arg) 
{ 
    int core = step_i++;  
       
    for (int i = core * maxelement / maxelement; i < (core + 1) * maxelement / maxelement; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < maxelement; ++j){
            for (int k = 0; k < maxelement; k++)
            {
                
                matrix3c[i][j]+= matrix1c[i][k] * matrix2c[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter rows for first matrix: ";
    cin >> r1c;
    cout << "Enter columns for first matrix: ";
    cin >> c1c;
    cout << "Enter rows for second matrix: ";
    cin >> r2c;
    cout << "Enter columns for second matrix: ";
    cin >> c2c;
    totalelement = r1c * c1c;
    int test = totalelement;
    maxelement = test;

 //generate matrix 1
    for(int i=1;i < r1c+1; i++)
    {
        vector<int>temp;
        for(int j=1; j< c1c+1; j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(i);
        }

        matrix1c.push_back(temp);
    }
    //generate matrix 2
    
    for(int i=1;i < r2c+1; i++)
    {
        vector<int>temp;
        for(int j=1; j< c2c+1; j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(j);
        }

        matrix2c.push_back(temp);

    }

        for(int i=1;i < r1c+1; i++)
    {
        vector<int>temp;
        for(int j=1; j< c1c+1; j++)
        {
            temp.push_back(0);
        }

        matrix3c.push_back(temp);
    }

  cout<< " a Matrix---------"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix1c.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix1c[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout<< matrix1c[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<< endl;
    }
cout<< " b Matrix---------"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix2c.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix2c[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout<< matrix2c[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<< endl;
    }

    cout<< " c Matrix---------"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix3c.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix3c[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout<< matrix3c[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<< endl;
    }

    pthread_t threadsss[totalelement]; 


    for (int i = 0; i < totalelement; i++) { 
        int* pt; 
        pthread_create(&threadsss[i], NULL, multi , (void*)(pt)); 
    } 
      for (int i = 0; i < totalelement; i++){  
        pthread_join(threadsss[i], NULL);  
    }


     //display product matrix 

    cout<< " Product Matrix---------"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix3c.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix3c[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout<< matrix3c[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<< endl;
    }


    return 0;



}
```

Error returned:

`seg fault at    matrix3c[i][j]+= matrix1c[i][k] * matrix2c[k][j];`

Can someone explain and show me how to fix this problem. Thank you!

Please forgive me for my messy code

This is part of the homework that I need to finish. Professor did mention we are allowed to use the internet for help. I already have all the other parts completed, but can not figure out what caused the seg fault. I went over this code about 20 times, and come to the conclusion that seg fault occurs inside of the nested loop.

This part of the program: calculate 2 matrices one thread for each element in the product matrix. (1 thread on each core)

Comment: Not sure if this is the only problem, but `matrix3` should have dimensions `r1c`x`c2c`, but now it has `r1c`x`c1c`. I suggest you implement a working matrix multiplication before adding any threads to that.

Comment: can you not use C++11? `void*` and bare pthreads for threading in C++ is complications you no longer need to worry about

Comment: Segmentation fault is basically trying to reach a memory location that doesn't exist. Please check if all the values you're trying to reach within   matrix1c and matrix2c exist (for all the indices you're trying to reach and use). That would imply checking dimensions of the matrices you've defined.